# Why is this Python traceback bad when executing a delegate function

Tags: python, events, delegates, callable, traceback

I have a search class that allows for an event delegate pattern. Other classes can register a function to be called when the search updates.

When there is an issue, the traceback is not showing the receiver function. For example:

My search class runs this...

```
# ----------- Search.py -----------
# class Search ...snip...
    def connect(self, fn):
        self.__updateDelegates.append(fn)

    def onTextChanged(self):
        # ...snip...
        # Execute all event delegates
        for fn in self.__updateDelegates:
            fn(search_pattern)
```

...and if the delegate function signature is wrong...

```
# ----------- Foo.py -----------
from search import Search
# class Foo ...snip...
    def __init__(self):
        search = Search()
        search.connect(self.onSearchUpdate)

    def onSearchUpdate(self): # <- Wrong on purpose. Should have another argument
        # Do something.
```

...I see this...

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "search.py", line 287, in onTextChanged
#     fn(search_pattern)
# TypeError: onSearchUpdate() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Notice the delegate function name is correct in the exception message but the traceback doesn't get that far.

The error is because the delegate signature should have a pattern argument. The problem is the traceback doesn't show where this error is happening. It should go back farther to the function object that the reference is pointing to.

Any idea how to fix this?

Note: I updated the code and explaination. I didn't want to muddle the issue with extra code, but I felt I needed to show more. This does NOT show what triggers the function `onTextChanged()`. This is actually part of a Qt widget implimentation and it runs this function when someone types in to a QLineEdit. So the pattern is, the parent widget creates the search widget then connects its function to be called when the text is changed. I hope this helps.

Comment: Read the error message. It says "... takes exactly 1 argument." That one argument is `self`. You have to add a `search_pattern` argument to your function definition as well.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  The exception is raised when you call the function with the wrong number of arguments.  The name is based on the actual function's `__name__` attribute, but the exception is not raised inside the function because it never gets that far.  The call `fn(self.re)` is the erroneous line.

Comment: can you show implementation of fn or self.__updateDelegates

Comment: I know WHY I get the exception. That is trivial and only the example. The issue is that the traceback is no accurate, or at least not expected in a real event delegate. I would expect the traceback to climb to the delegate function, which is the "user-level" function where the syntax error is actually originating from. They user used the wrong function signature in this example.

Comment: Updated the example with some more code and info.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `onSearchUpdate` is a method on class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,search_pattern):
        self.search_pattern=search_pattern
    def onSearchUpdate(self):
        pass #do something with search_pattern
```

Now in class `Search`, you somehow populate `__updateDelegates`:

```
pattern=['foo','bar','baz']

class Search(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.__updateDelegates=[]
       for i in range(3):
           self.__updateDelegates(Foo(pattern[i]).onSearchUpdate)
```

Now when you call `onSearchUpdate` via `__updateDelegates`, you just do something like:

```
for func in self.__updateDelegates:
    func()
```

This might not be how your code is structured (it's too hard to tell with your snippets), but hopefully this illuminates the problem.

Alternatively, maybe `onSearchUpdate` should have a second argument?

```
def onSearchUpdate(self,pattern):
   pass # snip ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking the time to answer. I updated my question with more info to help clarify. You are right on the cause of the error, but the question is about the traceback itself, not the cause. I know the cause but the traceback is not very helpful and someone else might have a hard time figuring out where they made the mistake.